# Next/link with slug and id

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want show url `'/post/[slug]'`, but I want get id of item then call `api` with `id`.
I can custom with query: `{ slug: 'next-js', id: 123}`, This issue, it show `url /next-js?id=123`

Comment: did you find answer?